# In Hyperledger Fabric, for the peers and client/cli, who is responsible for compiling the golang chaincode?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

It is obvious that the chaincode need to be compiled. Who is responsible for compiling it?

Comment: fabric sdk exposes apis to install, instantiate, query and invoke a chaincode. this fabric sdk will do the needful.

Comment: if i could not answer your question properly. please explain it further. i will do my best to answer it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I couldn't find the code fragment for compiling the chaincode in the fabric-sdk-node SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Chaincode is not compiled by the SDKs nor is it compiled when it is installed.  Chaincode is actually compiled by the peer when it is instantiated.

Comment: Yes, you're right. For fabric v0.6: The chaincode is built in a docker container triggered by the peer endpoint. The container takes the chaincode spec as input and output a chaincodedeploymentspec. The chaincodedeploymentspec is made up of the executable binary bytes of the chaincode. The format of the chaincodedeploymentspec as:  | pointer to chaincodespec | EffectiveDate | Codepackage | ExecEnv |.